# I live in Japan and want to send money to my credit card

Tags: credit-card, japan

I used to send money home to my parent’s account and they would then pay the bill. However my father is not in a position to do that anymore. 
Is there anyway to send money directly to the credit card? Japanese banks don’t have a sort code and setting up a direct debit will add another 7,000 yen to my bill.

Comment: Presumably "home" means USA, the credit card is issued by a US bank, and you have no bank accounts in the US at all?

Comment: I've never heard of a credit card that *doesn't* allow mail-in payments, as opposed to automatic payment from a bank account. Can you not write checks from your own account?

Comment: @chepner Pretty much no-one outside the USA uses checks any more.

Comment: @RupertMorrish Just because you don't use checks doesn't mean the credit-card issuer doesn't accept them.

Comment: I mean the Japanese bank won't issue them, or will charge Justin a fortune for honouring it.

Comment: Can you open an account through an international bank like HSBC (https://www.hsbc.co.jp/) or Citibank and use them for opening account in the US and then paying your bills?

Comment: What about we just answer the question ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which country your credit card was opened in.

In Australia, banks are often able to link your credit card to an internet banking account. Once you do that, even if you are unable to pay the credit card directly from Japan, you should be able to transfer money into a suitable account and use internet banking from Japan to pay off your credit card from that account.

If this is unavailable from your "home" country, contact your credit card provider for their advice on how to make payments from Japan.

Also, if you are eligible, consider opening a credit card account in Japan.  You can then either close your 'home' credit card account or keep it open and just pay its annual fees.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you don't have your own bank account in the USA, and won't be returning to the USA any time soon, in which case you could open one then.

If the situation is that your father can no longer make the credit card payments, perhaps he could open a subsidiary account for you and you could have your credit card company debit that account? Or use the bank's online payment system to make the credit card payment?

Failing that, there seems to be no shortage of people who will open up a bank account for someone they just met on Facebook.